Dropdown direction on react-native-element-dropdown
In my React Native app, I have a dropdown on the right side of the screen.
When I open the dropdown, it comes out of the screen and I can't see its elements.
It happens because the dropdown direction is from left to right. When I change containerStyle width it increases to the right side because of it.
I don't want to increase the width of the whole dropdown because it will ruin my app design, I want to change the item's containerStyle width and raise it to the left side.
Is there any way to do that?
Maybe change the direction of the dropdown from LTR to RTL? If yes, how to do that?
I searched for it in the documentation but didn't find any solution.

Usually such components are absolutely positioned in relation to their trigger element with left: 0 - so try overwriting the styles with left: auto; right: 0

That doesn't work... It moves the element to the Left side of the screen, far away from the button.

That was only a guess, based on how such components usually work. I can't find a live example anywhere for the thing you mentioned, and you did not provide one either, so I am currently not able to have a closer look.

What should I provide you that can help you?

A live example of that component in action, either on some real website, or set up in one of the various online react "playgrounds" available.
